# PHP Validate WKT values

Tags: php, wkt

I'm trying to validate data passing between client/server for a location-based application and I can't find any way to validate WKT strings in PHP. I'd prefer not to implement it myself, not because I'm lazy or incompetent but because I'm afraid of getting it wrong because I've never dealt with WKT before. Is there any way for me to validate or must I write my own validator?

Comment: No worries, actually I found that from one of the first results that came up which was a blog post that linked to that class.  I went ahead and made it an answer.  Tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this class [gisconverter.php](https://github.com/arenevier/gisconverter.php) which can convert WKT to various formats, or other formats to WKT.  It appears it will throw an exception if the WKT is not well formed also.

Example:

```
$decoder = new gisconverter\WKT(); # create a WKT decoder in gisconverter namespace
try {
    $geometry = $decoder->geomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((10 10,10 20,20 20,20 15,10 10)))'); # create a geometry from a given string input

    print $geometry->toGeoJSON(); # output geometry in GeoJSON format
} catch (InvalidText $itex) {
    echo "WKT was not well formed!";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "General exception.";
}
```